# Fedora installation - nouveau issue

Tags: fedora, drivers, nvidia, nouveau

I downloaded Fedora and created a bootable USB following the official guide.
When I boot from USB the system starts loading and the "F" icon completes.
Immediately after that I get into console mode and receive the message that an error had occurred.

Journalctl states : **[nouveau] boot pointer to tmds table invalid**.
I found out that this is a `nouveau` graphics drivers error message.

**How do I replace the prepackaged drivers to proceed with the installation?**
I've searched the forum and Google for solutions, but haven't found any actually.

Comment: Noveau is built into the kernel. You won't be able to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replace the built-in `nouveau` drivers, but you can deactivate them on system startup.

Boot from the Fedora installation medium, select the Start Fedora entry.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key and add the boot parameter `nouveau.modeset=0`.
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to boot into Fedora Live ... perform the installation.

Once it's finished, reboot and select the Fedora entry in the boot menu.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key and add the boot parameter `nouveau.modeset=0`.
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to boot into the installed Fedora operating system.

Log in - open a terminal and execute : `sudo vi /etc/default/grub`

Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rhgb quiet",
so that it reads : `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rhgb quiet nouveau.modeset=0"`

Save the changed file and execute one of these two commands to update the GRUB configuration :

`sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` (Fedora installation in EFI mode)
`sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` (Fedora installation in legacy BIOS mode)

Reboot the system, now you are using the intel graphics and the `nouveau` drivers are deactivated. You don't have to add the parameter any longer - alternatively install the proprietary NVIDIA drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you MD5 hash checksum iso before burn into CD or create bootable USB.

You can follow the official guide line here
https://getfedora.org/en/verify and make sure download ISO file from https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/ or you can try Fedora 24 which is Beta development and need to be tested

I'm using Fedora 23 and have 2 gpu and using Bumblebee

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 640M] (rev a1)
```

I also using bootable USB with **Fedora-Live-Workstation-x86_64-23-10.iso** as installer and It worked without problem. I create bootable USB using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) from my Windows 10 environment (I have dual boot OS).